# xpath expression for selecting parent with child nodes

Tags: html, xml, dom, xpath, yql

I currently use YQL to extract the contents of Wikipedia using xpath.

The xpath expression I currently use is `\\p` .This expression selects all the paragraph nodes stripping out all the child nodes like `<a>`, `<sup>`, `<strong>` etc..

Due to this i get an output for the Wikipedia football page like this. [Link here](http://developer.yahoo.com/yql/console/#h=select%20content%20from%20html%20where%20url%3D%22http%3A//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Football%22%20and%20xpath%3D%27//p%27)

In this output the links are stripped.

> From Wikipedia, the free encyclopedia
>
> .For other uses, see
>
> or soccer, , , , , and .Some of the many different games known as
>   football. From top left to bottom right:
>
> all involve, to varying degrees, a ball with the foot to score a . The
>   most popular of these sports worldwide is , more commonly known as
>   just "football" or "soccer". Unqualified, the word applies to
>   whichever form of football is the most popular in the regional context
>   in which the word appears, including , , , , , and other related
>   games. These variations of football are known as football "codes".
>   .....................and more

Expected output

> From Wikipedia, the free encyclopedia
>
> For other uses, see **Football (disambiguation)**.
>
> Some of the many different games known as football. From top left to
>   bottom right: **Association football or soccer**, **Australian rules
>   football**, **International rules football**, **rugby union**, **rugby league**, and
>   **American football**.
>
> Football **sports** all involve, to varying degrees, **kicking** a ball with
>   the foot to score a goal. The most popular of these sports worldwide
>   is association football, more commonly known as just "football" or
>   "soccer". Unqualified, the word football applies to whichever form of
>   football is the most popular in the regional context in which the word
>   appears, including American football, **Australian rules football**,
>   **Canadian football**, **Gaelic football**, **rugby league**, rugby union[1](http://developer.yahoo.com/yql/console/#h=select%20content%20from%20html%20where%20url%3D%22http%3A//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Football%22%20and%20xpath%3D%27//p%27) and
>   other related games. These variations of football are known as
>   football "codes".

*(bolder words are one which has links)*

So how to extract the paragraph along with its child nodes ?? I am new to xpath

Comment: I think you are looking for //p/*

Comment: //p/* gives me only the child nodes... i need the parent and the child nodes...

Comment: Sorry misunderstood your need I post the answer.

Comment: You have shown the output you're getting. Now please show the exact output you *want*. That will make things clearer. Otherwise, you'll just get more guessing.

Answer (score 0):

The right answer is `//p/descendant-or-self::*` in order to have parent and child nodes.

Comment: thanks for the try... but the child nodes are not within the parent node... how to get the child nodes in the right place within the parent node ?

Comment: @AakashChakravarthy - I think you're confused about what an XPath expression returns. It sounds like you want to see the *source* HTML as it appears below each of those paragraphs. An XPath expression selects nodes, so when you use alain's answer, you're getting a list of nodes that that expression matches. This is the *set* of all matches. It's not the *hierarchy*.

Comment: @AakashChakravarthy - In other words, if it matches a `p` *and* an `a` that is a child of that `p`, then it will return two nodes in the list (not *one* node that shows the children below it).

Comment: @lwburk I am completely new to Xpath.. I thought XPath returns nodes in a hierarchical manner. So is there any alternative way to get the required output ?